# Tool identity - 111 year old cutter jig?

Tags: identify-a-tool

[image]
 The square shank suggests its for a bit and brace not a lathe?

[image]
 Clearly a cutter that can be adjusted inward

[image]

[image]
Sliding part appears to be a square dovetail

[image]
 Patent date Dec 5 1911 perhaps.

[image]
This photo is a bit fuzzy, sorry.

I have no idea what this tool is - listed at https://www.trademe.co.nz/3703975458

Best guess is a groove cutter for a hand drill?

Comment: Could be a tubing cutter, but with a limited length for the part that can be cut off.

Comment: That square tapered end will fit a drill brace.  I can't imagine what trade this tool is for.

Comment: Inside of part with blade looks circular, like it should slide over a a round metal rod. Perhaps this is a manual threader for thick rods? Put into some machine and pushed onto rod to cut threads?

Comment: Reddit has a sub known as "what is this thing" that may provide an accurate answer in surprisingly short time.

Comment: Looks like its for boring a hole in the end of a rod. The rod could be round or square.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tenoning tool for a bit brace.

Since it's rather hard to describe how it works in words in a way that makes sense to people unfamiliar with one, I'm resorting to linking a video.

Example in use (of a slightly different design) shown [here.](https://youtu.be/U9rcNiu6yw4)

Comment: This makes sense the v will hold any rod and the cutter can be adjusted for the size the brace would provide the torque to turn the cutter+

Comment: Did a bit of googling before and one site(letools?) did have a picture of them.  Did look close but was not sure if close enough, did not show the base.